# Prototype and inheritance in JavaScript not functioning as I expect

Tags: javascript, inheritance

I've been learning about classes in JavaScript, the use of prototype and finally how to inherit.

From my understanding the below should:

1. Alert "John" due to `myInstance.getIt();` being called
2. Alert "Jack" due to `myInheritedInstance.getIt();` being called
3. `myInheritedInstance.getParent();` has been assigned to `.getIt()` in MyClass
4. This should then alert "John" when myInheritedInstance.getParent(); is called.

Instead what actually happens is:

1. Alert "John"
2. Alert Blank
3. Alert "Jack"

I have a feeling I've done something stupid or have misunderstood a fundamental concept here, so any help would be appreciated.

```
var MyClass = function() { };

MyClass.prototype.constructor = MyClass;
MyClass.prototype.name = "John";
MyClass.prototype.getIt = function () { alert(this.name); };

var myInstance = new MyClass();
myInstance.getIt();

//Now inheritance

var MyInheritedClass = function () { };
MyInheritedClass.prototype = new MyClass;
MyInheritedClass.prototype.constructor = MyInheritedClass;
MyInheritedClass.prototype.name = "Jack";
MyInheritedClass.prototype.getIt = function () { alert(this.name); };
MyInheritedClass.prototype.getItParent = MyClass.prototype.getIt.call(this);

var myInheritedInstance = new MyInheritedClass();
myInheritedInstance.getIt();
myInheritedInstance.getItParent();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The culprit is:

```
MyInheritedClass.prototype.getItParent = MyClass.prototype.getIt.call(this);
```

`.call` will *call* a function, not *return* one. So it will cause two issues: it calls it beforehand, and returns something that isn't callable (you get an error in the console). You'd have to do:

```
MyInheritedClass.prototype.getItParent = function() {
    alert(Object.getPrototypeOf(Object.getPrototypeOf(this)).name);
};
```

The problem is that `name` is not accessible through `this` anymore as it has been shadowed over by the inherited class. To get `name` of the original class, you have to walk up the prototype chain two times: `inherited instance -> inherited prototype -> original prototype`.

The line

```
MyClass.prototype.constructor = MyClass;
```

isn't necessary here, by the way. Restoring `constructor` is necessary in case you overwrite `prototype`, because `constructor` gets lost in that case. So in your case, it is necessary only for the inherited class.

Also, the line

```
MyInheritedClass.prototype.getIt = function () { alert(this.name); };
```

is superfluous, it's just the same as `MyClass.prototype.getIt` - which you inherited.

Note that JavaScript does not have real "classes", although their behaviour can be accomplished like this.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I think the issue is that I've been working from a not-so-correct tutorial. So there is no way to get at the base classes overridden methods and values via call? Is the example you show the only way to "get at" them?

Comment: And yes, I think that the addition of getIt within MyInheritedClass was my own little "faux pas" that I've brought into the situation!